# Batch file to get remote system information in a loop

Tags: command-line, batch

Sorry about the title, I struggled to explain it in one line.

I have a simple script which gets a remote systems status, and returns the line which contains the total memory, and outputs it to a file:

```
systeminfo /s:HOSTNAME | findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory" >> "D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt"
```

I have a text file which has all of the hostnames for every PC I want to check. How can I run this same command on each of the PC's in the text file, without having to make a batch file repeating this same line?

Also, If possible to also include the hostname in the log.

Thanks

UPDATE: I have come up with this, I will test it soon.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ("D:\All Pcs\pclist.txt") do (
    echo.   
    echo %%A >> "D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt"
    systeminfo /s:%%A | findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory" >> "D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get only total memory use wmic query - it is much faster.
for example:

```
...
wmic /NODE:"%%A" /APPEND:"D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt" MEMPHYSICAL get name, TotalPhysicalMemory
```

But you don't need batch file, better way is use file with coma delimited hostnames

```
wmic /NODE:@"D:\All Pcs\pclist.txt" /APPEND:"D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt" computersystem get name, TotalPhysicalMemory
```

You also can add global option /FAILFAST (timeout for connection to remote machine)

```
WMIC /FAILFAST:1000 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this by using the following:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in ("D:\All Pcs\pclist.txt") do (
    echo.   
    echo %%A >> "D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt"
    systeminfo /s:%%A | findstr /C:"Total Physical Memory" >> "D:\All PCs\RAM_LOG.txt"
)
```

Where pclist.txt is a list of all host names to scan.